# How do I get Visual Studio to show me what projects it will build without actually building?

Tags: visual-studio

Prior to doing a build, I would like to see which projects Visual Studio will build when it builds the solution.  Is there a way to get it to output this without actually doing the build?

I have looked at documentation and done some searches for previous questions on this, but found nothing.  Maybe it's not possible, but wanted to at least ask the question.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildPrediction

Comment: Hi, I posted Hans Passant's comment as an answer. If it is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution provided by Hans Passant: https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildPrediction.

This library runs a predictor against a calculated MSBuild ProjectInstance to predict the file and directory input that the project will read and the output directory that will be written to.